# Trim table column length over x charcters

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table and column. The column is varchar(8). I need to `trim` characters over 7.

TableA

```
LastName
 Smith
 McKinney
```

My below SQL TRIMs all rows. How do we only trim length over 7 characters?

```
update TEST set LASTNAME = SUBSTR(LASTNAME,1,LENGTH(LASTNAME)-1);
```

Comment: Simply use `update TEST set LASTNAME = left(LASTNAME, 7);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check the starting length:

```
update TEST set LASTNAME = SUBSTR(LASTNAME,1,LENGTH(LASTNAME)-1)
where LENGTH(LASTNAME) > 7;

1 row updated.

select * from test;

LASTNAME
--------
Smith
McKinne
```

You could replace `LENGTH(LASTNAME)-1` with numeric literal `7` in this case.